Notating small adjustments in rhythm
I'm trying to analyse/transcribe some rap music and one thing I've noticed in my listening is that occasionally in a given recording the syllables are shifted slightly off-rhythm for effect or some syllables are elongated longer for emphasis, whereas the surrounding notes are largely on-beat. As I understand it, this is similar to the idea of a microrhythm, except it happens irregularly instead of regularly throughout the piece/section.
Is there a good way to notate this kind of rhythmic adjustment without precisely marking the duration of each note (such as with a complicated tuplet, which would obscure the underlying rhythm)? I'm looking for a non-intrusive and imprecise way of saying "this note is slightly later/earlier/longer than notated".
I'd hope that because classical pieces are often played with this kind of rubato there'd be a good way to transcribe these kinda small and imprecise rhythm adjustments of a particular soloist (but perhaps that's not the goal of most classical notation?).

"Play with rubato"?

@Tim I'm looking for a way to notate exactly which notes are late/early/elongated/shortened for analysis purposes; normally "play with rubato" would suffice if you don't intend to mark exactly how one should play off grid i guess

There's no accepted 'classical' way of doing this that I know of.  But you could invent your own notation.  Backward- and forward-facing arrows perhaps. Or just 'e' for early, 'l' for late written over individual notes.
